# WPF - Ticking checkbox when clicking anywhere on a datagrid row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, datagrid

[image: Datagrid example]

The picture shows an example of some items added in my datagrid. Right now I can only change each rows checkbox by clicking on it but I would like to be able to click anywhere on each row to change that rows checkbox.

XAML of datagrid and row template:

```
  <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" BorderThickness="0" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ColViewSource},Mode=OneWay}"   AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="dataGrid" HeadersVisibility="None" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <DataGridRowsPresenter></DataGridRowsPresenter>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>

            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>

    </DataGrid>

 <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">

     <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="TTC">
                <Setter Property="Template"  Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TTC}"/>
            </DataTrigger>

           </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="TTC">
        <Grid Style="{StaticResource rowGridStyle}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30"/>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>


            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Style="{StaticResource commentboxStyle}" Text="{Binding Comment,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ></TextBox>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource textblockStyle}" Text="{Binding Text1,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <Label Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}" Content="{Binding Text2,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource RectBox}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsThreeState="True"/>
            <Path Style="{StaticResource dottedpathStyle}"/>

        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Any tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: Could you please post the XAML markup of your DataGrid?

Comment: @mm8 added xaml

Comment: And what are you doing in the PreviewMouseUp event handler?

Comment: @mm8 nothing actually, removed it from the code. (updated ^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a handler to your `DataGridRow` style that sets the `IsChecked` property of the data object to `true`:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="TTC">
            <Setter Property="Template"  Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TTC}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

---

```
private void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(e.Source is CheckBox))
    {
        DataGridRow row = sender as DataGridRow;
        YourDataClass dataObject = row.DataContext as YourDataClass;
        if (dataObject != null)
            dataObject.IsChecked = true;
    }
}
```

Make sure that `YourDataClass` implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raises the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of the `IsChecked` property.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent Code behind and use a `System.Windows.Interactivity.Behaviour`.

```
public class SelectedCheckBoxBehaviour : System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {

        AssociatedObject.MouseDown += AssociatedObject_MouseDown;

        base.OnAttached();
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement self = sender as FrameworkElement;

        if(self != null)
        {
            MyViewModel dataContext = self.DataContext as MyViewModel;

            dataContext.IsChecked = !dataContext.IsChecked;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.MouseDown -= AssociatedObject_MouseDown;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }
}
```

Namespaces

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:behaviour="clr-namespace:WpfApplication.Behaviour" 


<!-- ... --->


    <Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="30"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>


        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Comment,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ></TextBox>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text1,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Label  Content="{Binding Text2,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsThreeState="True"/>
        <Path />

        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviour:SelectedCheckBoxBehaviour />
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    </Grid>
```

This should work - [Tut](https://wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html)